# Create a relative path with parent directories steps

Tags: python, python-3.7, pathlib

Just in case I missed something and before I implement a own solution for the problem.

In our build system, I always have to work with relative paths to keep all projects moveable. Therefore the build scripts should generate relative paths to files.

Yet it seems there is no function in the python library, which can handle parent path steps as shown in the following example:

```
from pathlib import Path
dir_a = Path("/home/example/solution/project")
file_b = Path("/home/example/solution/config.h")
```

I would like to get a path to `file_b`, relative to `dir_a`. Therefore if I start in `dir_a`, the relative path would point to `file_b`.

The best result would be:

```
>>> file_b.relative_to(dir_a)
Path("../config.h")
```

Take this slightly more complex example:

```
from pathlib import Path
dir_a = Path("/home/example/solution/project_a")
file_b = Path("/home/example/solution/project_b/config.h")
```

The best result would be:

```
>>> file_b.relative_to(dir_a)
Path("../project_b/config.h")
```

Both examples using the `.relative_to` methods do not work and raise an exception:

```
ValueError: '/home/example/solution/project_b/config.h' does not start with '/home/example/solution/project_a'
```

The `os.path.relpath` method works as expected, but returns a string instead of a `Path` object:

```
>>> os.path.relpath(file_b, dir_a)
'../project_b/config.h'
```

So I wonder if I missed something here...

**How to I get a relative path with parent directories using Path objects?**

Why is the `relative_to` implementation of the `Path` object not working?

Comment: Can't you create `Path` object with the return value from `os.path.relpath`?

Comment: @yogkm Yes indeed, I can do this and probably, finally will do this. But I wonder, why I actually have to do this. Seems strange to me, if the Path object does everything else in a great way.

Comment: I've been wondering the same, staring at [the source code for `relative_to()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b6b711a1aa233001c1874af1d920e459b6bf962c/Lib/pathlib.py#L699-L730). I don't see a particular reason for choosing to have this limitation in `relative_to()`.